# node express - milliseconds to load classes

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am working with node express. So far I didn´t use a template engine. I create my html file and send it via `response.send(template);` It works fine.

Now, I have more complex tags like a checkbox with several classes. Loading the route in the browser, it takes some milliseconds till the classes are loaded. Means, first I have a checkbox and it changes then to a button. I am talking about milliseconds, but is there a way to load the classes before actually showing the page?

Do template engines like handlebars or pug have such a feature?

Happy for some help to look in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a template engine (`ejs`, `pug`, etc) you can then use the `res.render(...)` function. The `res.render(...)` function allows you to find data from the server side then send it over to the client along with the page.

Example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('view engine', 'ejs'); // Change ejs to your preferred view engine

app.get('/path/to/my/page', function(req, res) {
    // Get data
    res.render('example', { data: 'my-found-data' }); // Render the template 'example' with the data fetched
}
```

Additional documentation on using template engines can be found in official expresJS documentation here:

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: Thanks for the information! Meanwhile I read a lot about template engines. My data on the server side is allready a complete html file. In my case, there is no difference using response.send() or res.render().

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by classes here?

> but is there a way to load the classes before actually showing the page?

CSS classes? if yes, you can provide link to load CSS in header of HTML document you use to load it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Требуется авторизация</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</head>
<body>
```

See

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It loads bootstrap.min.css from /assets/bootstrap.min.css, and since its in header of page, all css classes are loaded before browser starts rendering page, so it renders it properly.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics for details on loading css

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link! I have all my links to css in the header. I am loading a class with special attributes and it looks like, that it is loading more css files afterwards. Now I have a pretty simple solution. I hide my main container in the body an set it to 'show' after all is loaded. It works perfect!